# Generating tool-tip for dynamic data in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I have a scatter plot similar to: http://plnkr.co/edit/MkZcXJPS7hrcWh3M0MZ1?p=preview

I want to give a tooltip on mouse hover for every combination. The tooltip code that i have currently does like:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div")  // tooltip code
   .attr("class", "tooltip")
   .style("opacity", 0);

 var circles = svg.selectAll(".dot")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "dot")
      .attr("r", 3.5)
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.petalWidth); })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.petalLength); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.species); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1.0);
         tooltip.html(d.petalLength+", "+d.petalWidth)
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
         tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

This will fail to return the correct tooltip for combinations other than petalWidth and d.petalLength.

Is there any way of knowing which combination has been selected and the associated numerical value for the combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this:

First store the tool-tip info in a new variable(displayX/displayY) like this:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
          d.displayX = d.petalWidth;//so displayX holds the x info
          return x(d.petalWidth);

        })
        .attr("cy", function(d) {
          d.displayY = d.petalLength;//so displayY holds the y info
          return y(d.petalLength);
        })
```

When you set the combo reset the variables accordingly.

```
 svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cy", function(d) {
          d.displayY = d[yAxy];//reset the variable displayY
          return y(d[yAxy]);
        });
```

Same for

```
svg.selectAll(".dot").transition().attr("cx", function(d) {
  d.displayX = d[xAxy];//reset the variable displayX
  return x(d[xAxy]);
});
```

Now in the tool tip mouse hover use variable(displayX/displayY)

```
 .on("mouseover", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
            .duration(200)
            .style("opacity", 1.0);
          tooltip.html(d.displayY + ", " + d.displayX)//use displayX and displayY
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX + 5) + "px")
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 18) + "px");
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(d) {
          tooltip.transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("opacity", 0);
        });
```

working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/onjQijW2cdZmBy2NKKtQ?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how do i increase the size of the circles on mouseover?
Also, the radius should go back to original size of mouseout?
i tried inserting .attr("r", 6.5) in the mouseover function and .attr("r", 4.5) in mouseout. 
This did not work.

Comment: You can do it like this  on mouse hover `d3.select(this).transition()
            .duration(200).attr("r", 10)` to increase the radius working code here http://plnkr.co/edit/onjQijW2cdZmBy2NKKtQ?p=preview